# Is there a way to avoid sending continuous requests to AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a restaurant menu page that contains around 500ish products. Every time a key is stroked in the search bar, the component will rerender and it will filter out whatever fits the best (like a normal search bar).

The problem is if I were to store image assets on AWS S3. Every time the component re-renders, it will send that many requests to the S3 and the billing would be massive as the result. See the below example for clearer ideas of what I'm trying to say:

- Container has 500 products
- First keystroke => Container re-renders down to 250 products
- Second keystroke => Container re-renders down to 100 products
- Last keystroke => Container re-renders down to 50

This means a total of **(500 + 250 + 100 + 50 ) = 900** image requests would be send to S3. And that's only one search for one user.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: add a caching layer. If you already requested a image there is no reason to re-download it, just re-use the image from the first download.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I'm not familiar with cache myself. Can you walk me through it a bit?

Comment: Not sure you math is right, if the first keystroke renders 250 images, and the second keystroke filters those 250 down to 100 , those 100 would already be cached by most browsers automatically - so it might not be as bad as you think.

Also, a lot of search bars I have seen, wait until the users has entered at least 3 characters before doing the first search - if you could live with that, it might save an awful lot of unnecessary traffic.

Comment: @E.J.Brennan But if I have `<img src='s3'/>`, doesn't it mean that every time that image renders, it'll send a request to s3?

Comment: @KyoKatarz usually not. The exact behavior depends on the browser, but most webservers will set the Cache-Control header to tell the browser how long content can be cached locally before it needs to be requested again. There is also clever ways in which checksums and last modified headers are automatically utilized to avoid excessive network usage - these keywords should be enough for a targeted google search ;-)

Comment: The browser will automatically cache content. Take a look at the **Network** tab in your browser Dev Tools to view the actual requests being sent to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Cloudfront is your guy, you should have no issues even with no knowledge about caching https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/getting-started/S3/